# Upload and Download stream to Azure Blob

Tags: .net, html, azure

I have a simple app where I'm doing a form post with a file type input to a WCF Service.  I'm trying to upload that file from the form post to an Azure blob and then download it by hitting the appropriate blob url.

What's happening now is I'm uploading a file to Azure but when I download it the file doesn't contain content.  For instance if I upload something.zip or something.gif I can download it from the url but they both won't contain anything.

I've read that this could be because the position of the stream is not set to 0. It won't let me set the position of the Stream "stream" below so I copied it to a memoryStream. Sadly that didn't resolve the issue.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "Upload")]
public string upload(Stream stream)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(exerciseContainer);
    CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference("myblob");

    Stream s = new MemoryStream();
    stream.CopyTo(s);
    s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    blob.UploadFromStream(s);

    return "uploaded";
}
```

Also I know the file is getting to the service through fiddler/breaks and I've successfully uploaded and downloaded files by hard coding in a file like this:

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\file.zip"))
{
    blob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

Edit: 
HTML

```
<form action='http://127.0.0.1:81/service.svc/Upload' method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnExercise" id="btnSubmitExercise"/>
</form>
```

Comment: "position of the stream is not set to 0." that resolved my issue, thank you +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks correct. But I have my doubts about the stream you're receiving. Are you sure it contains data? Could you try the following code? It returns the total amount of bytes received after uploading the blob.

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768]; 
    int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0; 

    do 
    { 
        bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead; 

        ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); 
    } while (bytesRead > 0); 

    blob.UploadFromStream(ms);

    return String.Format("Uploaded {0}KB", totalBytesRead/1024);
}
```

Comment: You are correct "Uploaded 0KB".  I suppose I'll add my client side code.

Comment: So the real question is why is my form not sending the file specified from the file input?